# Registering a windows service as automatic (not manual) but stopped

Tags: windows-services, registration, installshield

My team has an InstallShield configuration that registers a service. Since it's supposed to be automatically started upon a reboot, we can't set it to *manual*. According to the person responsible for it, InstallShield only gives the option of *automatic or manual* service setting.

Not being an expert on InstallShield, I'm still trying to help her figure out how to make the registration of the service *automatic* but *not started*. I haven't seen any such option in the client.

Am I looking at the wrong spot in InstallShield or is it not doable that way all together? If so, how should one approach the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a Windows Installer project type in InstallShield,  there are 2 different tables at play. ServiceInstall and ServiceControl.  It is completely possible to define the service using ServiceInstall with start type Automatic and not actually start the service during the installer.  It's the ServiceControl table that controls when to start/stop ( none, install, uninstall, both) a service.

For this situation I'd install the service as automatic and mark it for stop during both and start for none.  You may also want to set the REBOOT property to ask for a reboot at the end of the installer.

Another option is to investigate why you can't start it right away.  Is this a configuration problem or some other race problem?   Often time fixing that will simplify the deployment story and allow her to start it during the install.  One example would be if you don't have configuration data yet you have the service spawn off a background process that idles the service and puts a file system watcher on the config data.  As soon as the data is there the service goes from idle to active without stopping and starting it.